# Trouble with Queries/Datastore in Google App Engine - Go API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

I'm playing with Google App Engine using the Go APIs and despite everything I've tried I can't get the [Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query) to return data that is in the datastore. I can see that [Put()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Put) works as expected, and the entities are listable/accessible from inspection of the Admin Console available from `dev_appserver.py`

The struct I'm storing is defined this way:

```
type TweetData struct {
    Id int64 `datastore:",noindex" json:"id"`
    Text string `datastore:",noindex" json:"text"`
    Screen_name string `json:"screen_name"`
}
```

And my calls to query it are such:

```
func getDatastoreTweets(c appengine.Context, twitterUser string) []*TweetData {
    q := datastore.NewQuery("TweetData").Filter("Screen_name =", twitterUser).Order("-Id").Limit(10)

    var oldTweets []*TweetData
    if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &oldTweets); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Getall had non-nil error! %v\n", err)
    }   

    return oldTweets
}
```

For this query, `err` is never non-nil, but always returns 0 results, even when the Console tells me there are many. I've tried it without the [Filter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Filter) call as well, after the guestbook example the SDK provides, to no avail.

In case it's an issue with keys (unlikely if I understand correctly, because I'm querying on a property), the call to `Put` is as follows:

```
// tweetData passed in via parameter...
key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "TweetData", nil)
_, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &tweetData)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! ^_^

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need to pass a pointer to `[]*TweetData` to `GetAll`, a pointer to `[]TweetData` would also works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query ask for ordering by `Id desc`, while the index field is un-indexed, you should either:

- rewrite the TweetData annotation to index Id field:

`` Id int64 `json:"id"` ``

- Remove the Order clause of your query:

`q := datastore.NewQuery("TweetData").Filter("Screen_name =", twitterUser).Limit(10)`

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to update the question, but found this to be the answer. I expected indexing to only matter on the Filter stage, rather than the ordering of results it's already received... well, we know what they say about assumptions :-p

Comment: Yes, index are necessary every time you need to perform query operations that depends on entity property value.